Optimizing SQL Query Performance for Hierarchical Data Retrieval
I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve hierarchical data from a table stored in a SQL database. The table structure follows the adjacency list model, with each row containing a parent ID field linking to the ID of its parent row.
While this query works, it's not performing well with a large dataset. I've already optimized indexes on relevant columns, but I'm looking for further suggestions to enhance the query performance, perhaps through alternative query strategies or database-specific optimizations.
Here's a simplified version of the query I'm using:
WITH RECURSIVE HierarchicalCTE AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    parent_id,
    name,
    1 AS level
  FROM
    hierarchy_table
  WHERE
    parent_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    h.id,
    h.parent_id,
    h.name,
    p.level + 1
  FROM
    hierarchy_table h
  INNER JOIN
    HierarchicalCTE p ON h.parent_id = p.id
)
SELECT
  id,
  parent_id,
  name,
  level
FROM
  HierarchicalCTE;


While this query works, it's not performing well with a large dataset. I've already optimized indexes on relevant columns, but I'm looking for further suggestions to enhance the query performance, perhaps through alternative query strategies or database-specific optimizations.
Has anyone encountered a similar scenario with hierarchical data retrieval in SQL? Are there any advanced techniques or best practices I should consider to improve the efficiency of this query?
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

You might like this presentation I did comparing performance of hierarchical queries in MySQL 8.0: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4O0YQGTxjM

Please Tag your used DBMS.
